# Remove key if the value matches pattern

Tags: json, jq, key-value

I have following json and want to remove keys if the "value" matches specific pattern. Name of the keys are not fixed or pre-determined.

```json
{
    "resources": [{
        "tags": null,
        "properties": {
            "customerId": "1234-cbd9-42bc-9193-f6432a6ef0d4",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "sku": {
                "maxCapacityReservationLevel": 3000,
                "lastSkuUpdate": "Fri, 19 Mar 2021 16:38:12 GMT"
            },
            "createdDate": "Fri, 19 Mar 2021 16:38:12 GMT",
            "modifiedDate": "Fri, 19 Mar 2021 17:27:54 GMT",
            "status": {
                "events": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "firstTimestamp": "2021-03-19T16:40:59Z",
                    "lastTimestamp": "2021-03-19T16:40:59Z",
                    "name": "Pulling",
                    "type": "Normal"
                }]
            }

        }
    }]
}
```

Expected output

After removal of the following keys as values matched timestamp format.

- lastSkuUpdate
- createdDate
- modifiedDate
- firstTimestamp
- lastTimestamp

```json
{
    "resources": [{
        "tags": null,
        "properties": {
            "customerId": "1234-cbd9-42bc-9193-f6432a6ef0d4",
            "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
            "sku": {
                "maxCapacityReservationLevel": 3000,
            },
            "status": {
                "events": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "name": "Pulling",
                    "type": "Normal"
                }]
            }

        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and what is not working for you.

Comment: What is the timestamp format you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

```
"(?x:
   ^
   (?: \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T
   |   \\w{3},[ ][\\d ]\\d[ ]\\w{3}[ ]\\d{4}
   )
)" as $date_pattern |

( .. | select(type == "object") ) |= del(.[
   . as $o |
   keys_unsorted[] |
   select( $o[.] | type == "string" and test($date_pattern) )
])
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/Qvn4LcOFYE)

Adjust the pattern to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to delete key-value pairs from a JSON object is using `with_entries`, e.g. like so:

```
def matches:
  type == "string"
  and test("^[1-9]\\d{3}-\\d+-\\d|[1-9]\\d{3} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");

walk(if type=="object"
     then with_entries(if .value|matches then empty else . end)
     else . end)
```

You may of course wish to adjust `def matches:` according to your requirements, or to shorten the filter-argument of `with_entries` to:

```
select(.value|matches|not)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a superficially complicated but very efficient and actually quite simple solution.  It uses jq's streaming parser and would thus be especially suitable for very large JSON input(s).  Of course the `matches` filter as defined here should be taken as illustrative rather than definitive.

```
jq --stream -n '
  def matches:
    type == "string"
    and test("^[1-9]\\d{3}-\\d+-\\d|[1-9]\\d{3} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}");

  fromstream(inputs
    | select((length==2
                and (.[0][-1]|type)=="string"
                and (.[-1]|matches))
             | not) )
' input.json
```